# How to check if model have particular property or not?

Tags: php, oop, object, yii

I want to create one new model class, which will be extended in all other class. I want to auto set some fields when admin is addind/editing any record. i.e. createdDate, createdIp, updatedDate, updatedIp..etc.

Now my issue all fields will not be common in all models. So i want to check if object has createdDate property then only set it's value. If there will be no condition and model has not createdDate member then it will generate error. Below is code what i am trying. But it is not working.

```
public function beforeSave()
{ 
            if(isset($this->createdDate))
                    die('this model have createdDate field');
            else
                    die('this model does not have createdDate field');
}
```

Model may not straight forward, it may extend database table related class automatically. Below is printed object. createdDate field is in private list.

If i am using `var_dump(property_exists($this, 'createdDate'));`  it is giving me false.

```
AdvertisementRate Object
(
    [bannerLocation_search] => 
    [bannerType_search] => 
    [_md:private] => CActiveRecordMetaData Object
        (
            [tableSchema] => CMysqlTableSchema Object
                (
                    [schemaName] => 
                    [name] => tbl_advertisement_rate
                    [rawName] => `tbl_advertisement_rate`
                    [primaryKey] => advertisementRateId
                    [sequenceName] => 

                    [columns] => Array
                        (
                            [createdDate] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => createdDate
                                    [rawName] => `createdDate`
                                    [allowNull] => 
                                    [dbType] => datetime
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 
                                    [precision] => 
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:private] => 
                                    [_m:private] => 
                                )
```

Please help me to add this logic.

---

yes.. CActiveRecord is extended to my class.

MasterAdmin.php

```
class MasterAdmin extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function beforeSave()
    { 
                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump(property_exists($this, 'createdDate')); 
                exit;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extend MasterAdmin 
{
   // So whenever any record added or edited, beforeSave will be called and i can autoset createddate value.

}
```

Comment: is this going to help u ??? property_exists() .. Check manual for this -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php i think this is what u are looking for

Comment: Looking at your printed object it's unclear which object your `beforeSave()` method belongs to but in any case `createdDate` is not a property, it's an array key of the `columns` property belonging to the `CMysqlTableSchema` object. Assuming `beforeSave` is a method of that object it would be `isset($this->columns['createdDate'])` but it's hard to know for sure given the nesting.

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using activerecord?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#hasAttribute-detail

Comment: Have you looked at the link I provided, $this->hasAttribute('createdDate')   Should do what you want.

Comment: what about attributes within AR but not as column in db? This will return false, but class might have that property, `property_exists()` is better approach

Answer (score 5):

[`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) is what you're looking for.

This way, if the property exists but is set to `NULL`, the above function will return true as you would expect, while `isset()` would return a false leading you to believe the property does not exist.

Works for me. See [**example**](http://codepad.org/H11S4eWE)

Comment: property_exists is returning me false. I have my updated question. Please check.

Comment: In your example you have used public member. As i said these properties are coming dynamic based on mysql table. This is YII framework and my class is extending framework's model CActiveRecord e.g."class myClass extends CActiveRecord". So i can't use your code. Hope you understand.